# jq get the value of x based on y in a complex json file

Tags: json, jq

jq strikes again. Trying to get the value of `DATABASES_DEFAULT` based on the `name` in a json file that has a whole lot of `name`s and I'm completely lost.

My file looks like the following (output of an `aws ecs describe-task-definition`) only much more complex; I've stripped this to the most basic example I can where the structure is still intact.

```
{
    "taskDefinition": {
        "status": "bar", 
        "family": "bar2",  
        "volumes": [], 
        "taskDefinitionArn": "bar3", 
        "containerDefinitions": [
            {
                "dnsSearchDomains": [], 
                "environment": [
                    {
                        "name": "bar4", 
                        "value": "bar5"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name": "bar6", 
                        "value": "bar7"
                    },  
                    {
                        "name": "DATABASES_DEFAULT", 
                        "value": "foo"
                    }
                ], 
                "name": "baz", 
                "links": []
            },
            {
                "dnsSearchDomains": [], 
                "environment": [
                    {
                        "name": "bar4", 
                        "value": "bar5"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name": "bar6", 
                        "value": "bar7"
                    },  
                    {
                        "name": "DATABASES_DEFAULT", 
                        "value": "foo2"
                    }
                ], 
                "name": "boo", 
                "links": []
            }
        ], 
        "revision": 1
    }
}
```

I need the value of `DATABASES_DEFAULT` where the `name` is `baz`. Note that there are a lot of keypairs with `name`, I'm specifically talking about the one outside of `environment`.

I've been tinkering with this but only got this far before realizing that I don't understand how to access nested values.

```
jq '.[] | select(.name==DATABASES_DEFAULT) | .value'
```

which is returning

```
jq: error: DATABASES_DEFAULT/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select(.name==DATABASES_DEFAULT) | .value
jq: 1 compile error
```

Obviously this a) doesn't work, and b) even if it did, it's independant of the `name` value. My thought was to return all the db defaults and then identify the one with baz, but I don't know if that's the right approach.

Comment: `DATABASES_DEFAULT` should be in quotes, as it is a literal string, not a key name or function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to think of it as digging down into the structure, so first you open the outer layers:

```
.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[]
```

Now select the one you want:

```
select(.name =="baz")
```

Open the inner structure:

```
.environment[]
```

Select the desired object:

```
select(.name == "DATABASES_DEFAULT")
```

Choose the key you want:

```
.value
```

Taken together:

*parse.jq*

```
.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[] |
select(.name =="baz")                  |
.environment[]                         |
select(.name == "DATABASES_DEFAULT")   |
.value
```

Run it like this:

```
<infile jq -f parse.jq
```

Output:

```
"foo"
```

Comment: If I could +2 for such a detailed explanation I would, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[] |
  select(
    select(
     .environment[] | .name == "DATABASES_DEFAULT"
    ).name == "baz"
  )
```

The output is the object with the `name` key mapped to "baz".

```
$ jq '.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[] | select(select(.environment[]|.name == "DATABASES_DEFAULT").name=="baz")' tmp.json
{
  "dnsSearchDomains": [],
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "bar4",
      "value": "bar5"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar6",
      "value": "bar7"
    },
    {
      "name": "DATABASES_DEFAULT",
      "value": "foo"
    }
  ],
  "name": "baz",
  "links": []
}
```